# Android studio emulator error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android-studio, flutter, adb

I try to run a flutter app on Android Studio emulator and I get this error:

> adb: failed to install path-to-project\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
> Error launching application on sdk gphone x86 arm.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error when you build an app that doesn't have the native libraries for your given CPU architecture. For example if you built an app for Intel's x86 and are trying to install it on an emulator with ARM architecture.